# Limit the number of CPU cores used by an Windows service running from net start command

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-services

I am running an benchmark for PostgreSQL 12 on Windows 10. I want to limit the number of CPU cores used by PostgreSQL service to test how does the CPU performance affect TPU.

Now I am starting PostgreSQL service with following command:

```
 net start postgresql-x64-12
```

and I know how to limit the number of CPU cores for ordinary Windows application like:

```
 start /affinity 1 "" "C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe"
```

How can I limit the number of CPU cores used by an Windows service running from net start command? Is there an `/affinity` option equivalent in `net start` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. First, you *cannot* set CPU affinity to Windows system processes or services (see https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/0703/16/news151.html (Japanese)).

In my situation, I can run PostgreSQL process from `pg_ctl` command from cmd.exe with `/affinity` option like:

```
cmd.exe /c "start /affinity 1F /B c:\path\to\PostgreSQL\12\bin\pg_ctl.exe start -w -s -D C:\path\to\PostgreSQL\12\data"
```

Note that you *cannot* use `Start-Process` cmdlet and `ProcessorAffinity` property like this:

```
$app = Start-Process 'c:\path\to\PostgreSQL\12\bin\pg_ctl.exe' 'start -D C:\path\to\PostgreSQL\12\data' -PassThru -NoNewWindow
$app.ProcessorAffinity = 0x3
```

This causes `SetValueInvocationException` because `pg_ctl.exe` is immediately exit after it starts PostgreSQL instance.